# Vertical space around quotes is swallowed for first quote in TikZPoster

Tags: spacing, quoting, tikzposter

When I use the `quote` environment blocks of the `tikzposter` document class, the *first* quote does not have the appropriate vertical space around it.

This happens only for the very first quote; all subsequent quotes -- whether in the same block or another one -- have the correct spacing.

Why is that and how can I fix this is on a general basis (i.e. in the document preamble)?

---

Here a sample ouput:

[image: Sample output]

And here the MWE for it: (The MWE uses the `quoting` environment to show of the vertical skip better, but the problem occurs without the [`quoting` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/quoting) as well.)

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage[vskip=3ex]{quoting}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Quotes in TikZPoster}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{First Block}{
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{quoting}
    Quote 1 - \lipsum[2]
  \end{quoting}
  \lipsum[3]
  \begin{quoting}
    Quote 2 - \lipsum[4]
  \end{quoting}
  \lipsum[5]
}

\block{Second Block}{
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{quoting}
    Quote 1 - \lipsum[2]
  \end{quoting}
  \lipsum[3]
  \begin{quoting}
    Quote 2 - \lipsum[4]
  \end{quoting}
  \lipsum[5]
}

\end{document}
```

And here the output.